# pthreads mutex lock assertion error

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have two threads (created via `pthread_create`). They are `join`-able threads ( not detached ).
But i dont do `pthread_join` on them, wrong i know, but question is not that.
Threads share a data structure on heap with mutex locks inside it. 
Only the the thread who locks it, unlocks the mutex.

I am getting following error in some random cases.

```
pthread_mutex_lock.c:62: __pthread_mutex_lock: Assertion `mutex->__data.__owner == 0'
```

Question is in this case if thread2 properly unlocks the mutex and does `pthread_destroy` and dies via `exit(1)`, now if thread1 tries to lock the same mutex after `pthread_destroy`, would you get "this" error or some other error?

Answer (score 2):

Which error you get, if any, when you break the rules depends on the platform. So you'll have to test it yourself to know for sure. This is a "you are not allowed to even try this" condition, so there's no rule for what has to happen when you do it.